# Long-running-to-death migration / find_each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

Running Rails 3 with PostgreSQL,

I've a migration, updating millions of small records.

```
Record.find_each do |r|
  r.doing_incredibly_complex_stuff
  r.save!
  puts "#{r.id} updated"
end
```

Since I think ActiveRecord wraps such updates in a transaction, the "commit" time is very long and the memory taken is HUGE, while every record has been "printed" on screen in the above example.

So, could I run this find_each outside a transaction -- while it is quite safe--, saving a lot of "commit" time and memory?

A kind of *ActiveRecord::Base.without_transaction do ... ; end* I guess :-)

OR :
I'm wrong, migrations are not wrapped into transactions, and the time I see is just SQL update statements applying?

EDIT : It seems threre is no link with transactions, here's the stack trace I got once I interrupt the migration, when all have been printed on screen and the RAM decreasing from 500MB free to ~30MB :

```
IRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!!
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:46:in `call'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:46:in `method_missing'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:978:in `flatten'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:978:in `block in select'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:977:in `map'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:977:in `select'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:56:in `select_all'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:467:in `find_by_sql'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `to_a'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:356:in `inspect'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/clement/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@gemset/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

EDIT(2): Wow. It turned out it was very long because find_each returns all elements after it iterated.

I tried :

```
Record.tap do |record_class|
  record_class.find_each do |r|
    r.doing_incredibly_complex_stuff
    r.save!
    puts "#{r.id} updated"
  end
end
=> Record(id: integer, ...)
```

So it gave back the console instantly as expected. :)

But then I still see a strange behavior : RAM doesn't free. Instead once I exited term, RAM still plunges...

Maybe my solution with tap is not satisfying? Is it still mass selecting?  How would I avoid the mass select after the find_each?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your updates to the database really as simple as `r.update_attribute(:some_column, 'some_value')`?

Comment: I would update_all, but indeed, it's a little more complex since I have method calls on each object. I guess I have to change my example :)

Comment: have a look at http://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/ They suggest that activerecord without transactions is actually taking longer than with them. The big memory footprint and the low speed are probably due to activerecord itself. Can you rewrite the migration with raw SQL?

Comment: Thanks for this link, I was looking at it a few hours ago -- I'm now wondering if I could do something simpler, using AR in this specific case of migration and find_each.

Comment: I could understand that trying to work simple with AR is not a good approach for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `ActiveRecord::Migration` nor `find_each` do anything to wrap your code in a database transaction. The `r.save!` will be wrapped in an individual transaction that covers any cascading effects of the save.

As in the comments above, using `update_all` or a raw `execute` will be faster for mass updating. I have no way to tell if that would be appropriate for what you're doing. Also, if you're having memory issues, you should be able to tweak the batch size on `find_each` and see if it has an effect. If not, you may be holding onto those objects somewhere.

Comment: The thing that makes me uncomfortable, is the order things happen : I've got all my printed outputs on screen, and that's after that my laptop seems go with hard working time !

Comment: That's really weird. If you `Ctrl-C` it while it's working hard, can you tell anything from the trace?

Comment: Thanks I'll report that ASAP!

Comment: Hi, Austin I just posted the stack trace. Looks like [line 978 of AR's Postgres adaptater](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1081ea66a3d864f310a1a55f22229af4e10436a7/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L978) is performing a select. I don't know how to investigate more !

Comment: I'm pretty sure the behavior of `find_each` is not the problem. Wrapping it in a block will not change what work it does. It returns `self`, which will be the class anyway. It does, however, seem to be inspecting the whole collection. Perhaps you could post a more realistic version of the code you're running?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could structure the method to add a last statement to serve as a return value, rather than returning the return value of find_each.  You could replace the last "end" with

```
end ; nil
```